# C++ project reference lower .NET causes Access violation reading location

Tags: c++, .net, visual-studio-2010, dll, visual-studio-2008

I created two new C++ projects using VS2010, one is DLL and one is console app. I flagged the class in DLL for export and the console app reference the DLL project. Very simple things and it works.

But, when I changed the DLL toolset to v90 (VS2008 installed), I am getting Access violation reading location error.

It seems to me, the two C++ projects must be compiled by the same toolset v100 which both targets .NET4.0. If there is a mismatch between the two, it causes access violation error.

Does anyone know how to resolve this? I could move the source code from DLL project into the console app project, but, that's rather ugly.

Is this a limitation of lower version of .NET? Maybe higher version of .NET has better backward compatibility on C++ dlls?

Thank you

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with .NET.  Having two difference versions of the runtime support library in a single process causes this kind of problem.  Designing your DLL interface so this can still come to a good end is rocket science that you are probably not quite ready for when you have to ask this question.  So keep the toolset the same to get ahead.  Or *do* use .NET, it provides a VM that ensures that every module can agree about how to allocate and release memory.  The feature that native C++ does not have.

Comment: Hi Hans, thanks for the quick response. Is there a way to "do use .NET"? I can change it to Managed C++. Or you mean switching to C#? The projects are old and massive, so, doing interfaces or porting it to C# would not be feasible. If there is some less painful way to manage this, would be really great. Thank you.

Comment: Rewriting an old massive codebase and redesigning the DLLs are the painful ways of course.  Ensuring that all the code is compiled with the same toolset is not painful.  At all.

Comment: I guess I will include the source file inside the same project for now. Thanks for helping.